# How to return a varchar type in a select of a free string. example: Select 'Test' as field from table

Tags: postgresql

Unlike other databases, PostgreSQL returns a TEXT type by default every time you run a select with a free string. Example:

```
SELECT 'Text' as FIELD FROM TABLE
```

in this case above the field `FIELD` will be returned with type `TEXT`

Does anyone know if it is possible to change some parameter in PostgreSQL so that it returns a `CHAR` or `VARCHAR` type in the above case?

Firebird and Oracle return a `CHAR` type.

I know this would be solved with a CAST however for this I would have to replicate the same for all SQL's of the system besides having to make using `CAST` a standard routine of developing new SQL's.

Anyway, does anyone have any idea of ​​anything that might have changed? I'm studying the files `pg_cast.h` and `pg_type.h`

Comment: This might help you   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13676816/postgres-data-type-cast

Comment: Why do you need a varchar instead of text?

Comment: Because TEXT types are not displayed in grids of our system. Casting commands would be a solution, but it would take a lot of time to analyze all the commands in our system. In addition to increasing the chances of bugs occurring. Our system is programmed to be compatible with 3 different database types

Comment: We were able to change the postgresql function return to varchar(ex.: ltrim, rtrim, sub_str ..) through pg_proc.h. But with free strings we still have not made any progress.

Comment: `with a as ( select 'hello'::varchar as b from table ) select a.b,pg_typeof(a.b) from a;`   casting seems to work... maybe the problem is in the library.  - can you post example code?

Comment: also sql compliant casting works `select cast ( 'rwrwef' as character varying) as field from t`

Comment: Your pain is understandable, did you find any solution?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you just need to cast it.

```
 SELECT CAST( 'Text' as CHARACTER VARYING(99999) ) as FIELD FROM TABLE;
```

or using an alternative pg-specific casting syntax.

```
 SELECT 'Text'::varchar as FIELD FROM TABLE;
```

If you select a string constant and don't cast it to something it has type `unknown`.  but I'm guessing your connection library converts this to the preferred postgres string type 'text'